# Computing the homology of some quotient of $S^{3}$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

> $\textbf{Question}$ Let $X$ be the quotient space of $S^{2}$ under the identifications $x\sim -x$ for $x$ in the equator $S^{1}$. Compute the homology groups $H_{i}(X)$. Do the same for $S^{3}$ with antipodal points of the equatorial $S^{2}\subset S^{3}$ identified.

I was trying to solve the second part about $S^{3}$ but was not sure if I did it right, particularly about glueing the 3-cells $P,Q$ below.

Let the equator be given by

[image]

where $v$ is a 0-cell, $e$ a 1-cell and $A$ a 2-cell. Attach a 3-cell $Q$ along $AA$, another 3-cell $R$ along $AA$. We get the cellular chain complex
$$0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}^{2}\xrightarrow{d_{3}}\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{d_{2}}\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{d_{1}}\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow0.$$
We know $H_{0}(X)=\mathbb{Z},H_{k}(X)=0$ for $k\geq 4$. Also,

(i) $d_{3}Q=d_{3}P=2A$ and $\ker d_{3}=\mathbb{Z}\langle P-Q\rangle$, im$d_{3}=2\mathbb{Z}\langle A\rangle$,
(ii) $d_{2} A=2e$, $\ker d_{2}=0$, im$d_{2}=2\mathbb{Z}\langle e\rangle$, 
(iii) $d_{1}e=0$, $\ker d_{1}=\mathbb{Z}\langle e\rangle$, im$d_{1}=0$.

Therefore, $H_{1}(X)\simeq\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $H_{2}(X)=0$, $H_{3}(X)\simeq\mathbb{Z}$.

Please let me know if this looks right.

Comment: How can we have $\text{Im}~d_3\neq 0$ and $\ker d_2 = 0$, since $\text{Im}~d_3\subset \ker d_2$?

Comment: $@$Austin C, Thanks. I didn't notice that.